# Canonical and Compatibility Decomposition_Mapping values Chart/Table

Tags: unicode, normalization, unicode-normalization

I have been working on [Unicode Normalization](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15/) for NFKC. In section 1.3 I found the following line-

> For NFKC or NFKD, one does a full compatibility decomposition, which
>   makes use of canonical and compatibility Decomposition_Mapping values.

From where I can get canonical and compatibility Decomposition_Mapping values?

Comment: Did you see 2013Asker's answer? It looks right to me. Please consider clicking the "Accept" checkmark to give credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to http://old.kpfu.ru/eng/departments/ktk/test/perl/lib/unicode/UCDFF301.html, the 5th field on the following file contains the Decomposition_Mapping values:

http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt